# Triple quotes in PHP?

Tags: javascript, php, onclick, quote

Firstly, sorry for my bad english.
I've a problem on that :

```
        print "<option onclick='javascript:redirectionJavascript(this.value,$date)' selected value='$id_user'>$name</option>";
```

My problem is $date is equals to '2018-03-09' and if I launch that code javascript will receive '2003' cause without quote Javascript does a subtraction. 
So i need to put quote around $date but I dont know how.

Thank you for your answers.

Comment: Most of this output is static, only in two places are you dynamically inserting values - so it might make more sense not to output the whole thing via PHP in the first place. http://php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.phpmode.php

Comment: `onclick='javascript:` - please go research why this is nonsense.

Comment: You can escape the double quotes (http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php), but it might be easier to close out the PHP brackets, output the HTML, and insert a php snippet to echo.

Comment: try this 
        print "<option onclick='javascript:redirectionJavascript(this.value,'".$date."')' selected value='$id_user'>$name</option>";

Comment: ```<?php
    $date = '2003-5-25';
    $id_user = 41;
    $name = 'dennis';
    print "<option onclick='javascript:redirectionJavascript(this.value,\"$date\")' selected value='$id_user'>$name</option>";
?>```  you can escape the quotes character using slash

Comment: Why are you posting answers as comments?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Putting a quote in a string is done by escaping it. So if I want to print "quote" with the quotations, I would do

```
print "\"quote\""
```

So in your case this should be the answer:

```
print "<option onclick='javascript:redirectionJavascript(this.value,\"$date\")' selected value='$id_user'>$name</option>";
```

Comment: Thank you, it's working perfectly. I'm new on this forum and you're the most effective forum community I've ever seen